# async.js filter function nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

i managed to make work the folowing filter

```
var async = require('async');
var fs = require('fs');
async.filter([3, 4, 5, 6, 7], fa, function(err, results) {
  console.log(results);
  //console.log("ultimcc",cc);
});

function fa(as, callback) {
  var cc = {};
  for (i = 1; i < as; i = i + 1) {
    cc[i] = i;
  }
  console.log("inside", as, cc);
  if (as > 4) {
    callback(null, as)
  }
  if (as <= 4) {
    callback(null, null)
  }
}
```

In this example i try to filter anything that is greather than 4
Ignore cc variable.
problem is ....It do not match docs on async module
https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/v1.5.2/README.md
I try some varinats on highter variants,...same nonsense

Can someone help me write in correct way only with async module?

Comment: The code does what I expect when I run it with [RunKit](https://npm.runkit.com/async). It returns `[5, 6, 7]` and logs `"inside", 3, {1: 1, 2: 2}` (and so on)... i don't get your problem.

Comment: Me too, the code works like it is. What result do you want exacly?

Comment: wanted to learn a bit filter but docs on version 1.5.3 are a mess

Answer (score 0):

I don't know but you can simply filter array without using the async module. But as you have stated that you have to use async module only then

```
var async = require('async');
var fs = require('fs');
let cc = {};
async.filter([3, 4, 5, 6, 7], (res) => {
    if (res <= 4) {
        cc[res] = res;
    }

});
console.log(cc);
```

Comment: ty it is interesting also the way the final callback is avoided

Answer (score 0):

Is better to use `.filter()` of Array Object but if you prefer to use async this is a example of code:

```
const async = require('async');
const fs = require('fs');

async.filter([3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
  (as, callback) => {
    if (as > 4) callback(null, as);
    else callback();
  }, (err, results) => {
    if (err) console.error(err);
    else console.log(results);
  });
```

the alternative whitout async module is this:

```
let result = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7].filter(as => as > 4);
// equal to write -> let result = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7].filter(function (as) { return as > 4; });
console.warn(result);
```

Comment: ty is very well made, i was forced to ask because i need for the rest of functions and inside docs.....
    arr - An array to iterate over.
    iterator(item, callback) - A truth test to apply to each item in arr. The iterator is passed a callback(truthValue), which must be called with a boolean argument once it has completed.
    callback(results) - Optional A callback which is called after all the iterator functions have finished.

Comment: Wich other functions?